# NoActivityFound exception occurs occasionally

Tags: android

What are the reasons having exceptions like

> - ActivityNotFound
> - Activity Destroyed
> - Fragment Destroyed

etc?
When I run my android app, It crashes occasionally because of these exceptions and can not find the reason.This is not happening always. I'm new to android and if there are any solutions for these kind of exceptions, please guide me.

below is a copy of a logcat ,

> 

```
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.eleos.retailposplus.bbpos, PID: 4857
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.eleos.retailposplus.bbpos/com.eleos.retailposplus.report.ui.invlist.InvoiceListUI}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4572)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4628)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1762)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6949)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1837)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStop(FragmentManager.java:3250)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStop(FragmentController.java:245)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:641)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop(AppCompatActivity.java:184)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1381)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7452)
11-13 19:49:16.505  4857  4857 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4567`enter code here`
```

Comment: Next time it happens please copy and paste the crash log in the post.

Comment: it happens in many activities.

Comment: Doesn't matter which activity it happens to. Without that, no one would be able to help.

Comment: He means watch your Android Studio's Logcat and copy the stack trace (which indicates reason of crashing), then paste it here..

Comment: ActivityNotFound happens when You forget to include Your activity in Manifest. But still you should provide an error log.

Comment: Log is included.

Comment: Log is included with the question above please refer. is it enough

Answer (score 1):

`ActivityNotFound` indicates that the OS couldn't find the activity you starting this could be due to some facts:

1. The activity belongs to your app however you never register it into your app manifest.
2. You starting another application but the OS couldn't find the app/activity you started to launch.

for the first point, all you need to do is to include the activity in your manifest by doing something like

```
<activity android:name="package.activityClassName"/>
```

for the second point you'll need to catch the crash with

```
try {} catch(ActivityNotFound e) {}
```

and do something in catch to inform the user that they need the specific app installed in order for you to launch it.

`Fragment Destroyed` that indicates that the fragment is being destroyed that could happen due to the crash or the fragment being detached when the activity is destroyed.

---

After seeing the logcat, that might be due you accessing the activity `fragmentManager` but you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much k0sh. I have added it in manifest already. app works normally, but this issue happens occasionally.

Comment: check my edit. dont use fragmentManager on nestedFragments but use the fragment fragmentManager which is called childFragmentManager

Comment: Thank you. But I have used getChildFragmentManager() in nested fragments. but this happened though i used getChildFragmentManager() in nested fragments . please help